# ffmpeg text watermark bottom left

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

I have found out how ffmpeg can add image watermark at the bottom left of a video

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\test.mp4" -i "C:\test\watermark.png" -filter_complex "overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10" "C:\test-watermark.mp4"
```

but I am looking for a way to add text (white, 12px text, with black shadow to make the text readable) instead of an image. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) filter.

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\test.mp4"
 -vf "drawtext=text='Place text here':x=10:y=H-th-10:
               fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontsize=12:fontcolor=white:
               shadowcolor=black:shadowx=5:shadowy=5"
"C:\test-watermark.mp4"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is working like a charm.

Comment: @Gyan Can you let us know how to write 2 line text using this. Have used drawbox as well

Comment: http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/drawtext.htm.gz for doc

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all and watermark each file

```
    foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem){
$file_name=$f.Name.replace($f.Extension,"")
$file_ext=$f.Extension
$watermark_text='KARACHI AI - MEETUP # 16 | AI in Agriculture and Real Estate' 
ffmpeg -i $file_name$file_ext -vf "drawtext=text="$watermark_text":x=10:y=H-th-10:fontsize=40:fontcolor=white" -preset ultrafast $file_name"_WM"$file_ext}
```